# Insert one db's different tables data to other db's single table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

i'm running into a complex problem, the data in a db has three tables.

**First_DB**

```
-- default_users
id  username    email        password
1   Timbog  Timbog@mail.com  vads7y3kkjdfa
2   Marta   Marta@mail.com   vads7y3kkjdfa

-- default_album
album_id   album_name  default_user_id
   1        Name_Tim       1
   3        Katarina       2
-- default_album_img
img_id      image_file    album_id 
  3       1320229733.jpg     1
  4       3320229733.jpg     3
```

**Second_DB**

```
--users
user_id   user_name     user_email       user_pass     user_image
   1        Timbog    Timbog@mail.com   vads7y3kkjdfa  1320229733.jpg 
   2        Marta      Marta@mail.com   vads7y3kkjdfa  3320229733.jpg
```

The approach i used to solve this problem is to first fetch all data by inner join, should i use full outer join and insert the required field to my table, the following query is actual by which i'm trying to make it wor:

```
INSERT INTO bbpin.users ( user_name, user_pin, user_email, user_password, user_img)
SELECT  default_users.username, default_users.bb_pin, default_users.email, default_users.password
FROM bbmpins_pins.default_users
INNER JOIN bbmpins_pins.default_album_images
ON default_album_images.album_id = default_users.id;
```

i miss the thing how do i compare two table's id in this join maybe? or this query is all wrong by approach?
By two tables which are sepearte in First_DB there could be multiple record how do we trunk them to last entry only ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to retrieve all rows from the `default_users` table. And along with each row, also return the corresponding row(s) from `default_album` table. And along with that, the corresponding row(s) from `default_album_img` table.

Given the example data, a query using inner joins would return the specified result:

```
 SELECT u.id             AS user_id
      , u.username       AS user_name
      , u.email          AS user_email 
      , u.password       AS user_pass
      , i.image_file     AS user_image
   FROM default_users u
   JOIN default_album a
     ON a.default_user_id = u.id
   JOIN default_album_img i 
     ON i.album_id = a.album_id
```

That query will work for the example data.

But, if there is a row in `default_user` which doesn't have a matching row in `default_album`, then an inner join won't return that row:

```
 -- default_users
 id  username    email            password
 3   branstark   bran@winterfell  warg2
```

Or, if there are two or more rows in `default_album` that match a given user, then the query will return two copies of the row from default_user...

```
-- default_album
album_id   album_name  default_user_id
  1        Tim2          1
```

Without a specification of what is to be returned in those cases, we can't recommend a query.

Comment: or we could just do it one by one, the patty approach insert all data from one table to another without the conflicting table and when it gets done match the fk with the album key and insert it, still need to deal those multiple values

Comment: what if i remove primary key of users table as unique key, will it help. can we do that?

Comment: The query is really going to depend on what you are attempting to achieve. If the inner join query produces a set that is "missing" rows or has "duplicated" rows, then that can be addressed. We could use OUTER joins to avoid "missing" rows, or we could avoid a join by using a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. To avoid "duplicate" rows, we could use either a GROUP BY and an aggregate expression, or (again) a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. It really depends on what result you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your current approach using a `JOIN` but could modify it a bit to be more readable and also you will have to join the relation table

```
INSERT INTO bbpin.users (user_id, user_name, user_pin, user_email, user_password, user_img)
SELECT du.id,
du.username, 
du.bb_pin,
du.email, 
du.password,
dai.image_file
FROM bbmpins_pins.default_users du
JOIN bbmpins_pins.default_album da ON du.id = da.default_user_id
INNER JOIN bbmpins_pins.default_album_images dai
ON dai.album_id = da.album_id;
```

Comment: as we have to take image value from third table it gives error of count straight away

Comment: same error, column count doesn't match value count. I guess there could be multiple insertion of albums by user and that maybe the problem ?

Comment: @HabibRehman, that's a simple one and you are expected to get by yourself. Anyways, see edit in answer again

Comment: or should i remove users primary_key as a unique key can we do that?